# Confused by this reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($)
{
$.vari = "$.vari";
$.fn.vari = "$.fn.vari";

// $.fn is the object we add our custom functions to
$.fn.DoSomethingLocal = function()
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        alert(this.vari);    // would output `undefined`
        alert($(this).vari); // would output `$.fn.vari`
    });
};
})(jQuery);

// $ is the main jQuery object, we can attach a global function to it
$.DoSomethingGlobal = function()
{
    alert("Do Something Globally, where `this.vari` = " + this.vari);
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div").DoSomethingLocal();
    $.DoSomethingGlobal();
});
```

I am confused why in the `$.fn.DoSomethingLocal` function, `$(this).vari` is the string "$.fn.vari" and not "$.vari". I thought that the `this` reference in the `each` call gives a dom object, so calling `$(this)` returns a standard jquery object with prototype `$`, not `$.fn`.

How does this happen?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking, but are you aware that $(this) inside of an .each loop refers to the current item in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

The `jQuery.fn` namespace is inherited by jQuery objects. So if you write `$.fn.somewhat` you now can access this by `$().somewhat`. That is why any jQuery plugin has to extend the `jQuery.fn` object/namespace.

The pattern `jQuery.somewhat` would just extend the plain object with `somewhat`. That is as good as `window.somewhat` or `anyobject.somewhat`.

`$.fn` has a prototypal inheritance, that is all the magic.

```
return this.each(function()
{
    alert(this.vari);    // would output `undefined`
    alert($(this).vari); // would output `$.fn.vari`
});
```

In this context, `this` always refers to the object of invocation, that is, a `jQuery object`. Since all jQuery objects inherit from `jQuery.fn` you are getting `$.fn.vari` here.

**note**

Within the scope of `$.fn`, `this` references to a **jQuery object** !

Within the scope of `.each()`, `this` references to a **DOM node** !

Why?

Javascript's `.apply()` function allows you to specify the context in which you want to execute a function. That principle is used by "Resig & the boys" to "derefer" `this`.

Comment: +1 As I understand the code, `jQuery.fn` is a reference to `jQuery.prototype`. http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L61

Answer (score 0):

when iterating through a jquery object with .each(), this referes to the element NOT wrapped in a jquery object. The method jQuery.vari() is on the jquery object, not the elements, so you have to wrap the element in a jquery object before you can call the $.vari() method.